# Solving for $x$ in $9^x=18$

Tags: solution-verification, exponential-function

So I was again looking through the homepage of Youtube to see if there were any math video that I thought that I might be able to solve when I came across this video by Learncommunolizer asking for the value of $x$ in [$$\color{black}{9^x=18}$$](https://youtu.be/02g-q1v4w0o)which I thought I might be able solve. Here is my attempt at solving the aforementioned question:$$9^x=18$$$$3^{2x}=18$$$$3^{2x-1}=6$$$$3^{2x-2}=2$$$$(2x-2)\ln3=\ln2$$$$2x-2=\dfrac{\ln2}{\ln3}$$$$2x=\dfrac{\ln2}{\ln3}+2$$And knowing that$$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{ad+bc}{cd}$$Also$$2=\dfrac{2}{1}$$$$2x=\dfrac{\ln(2)+2\ln(3)}{\ln(3)}$$$$\therefore x=\dfrac{\ln(2)+2\ln(3)}{2\ln(3)}$$**My question**

---

Is the solution that I have achieved correct, or what could I do to achieve the correct solution/attain it more quickly?

Comment: shouldnt it be $\frac{ad+bc}{bd}$

Comment: @User0 No, it would be, in fact, $\dfrac{ad+bc}{cd}$ (you don't multiply $d$ by $b$)

Comment: "And knowing that$$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{d}=\dfrac{ad+bc}{cd}$$ This is not correct. Try an example.

Comment: @CrSb0001  User0 is correct.  Moreover, you used the formula $\frac{ad + bc}{cd}$ in your calculations with $a = \ln 2$, $b  = \ln 3$, $c = 2$, and $d = 1$.  Notice that $\frac{ad + bc}{bd} = \frac{\ln 2 + 2\ln 3}{ln 3}$.

Comment: well if that were the case, then 2x=$\frac{ln2+2ln3}{2ln3}$ and x would then be $\frac{ln2+2ln3}{4ln3}$

Comment: Also your solution is correct with an error of 0.0000000006

Comment: @User0 That's literally an error of $0.000000046$%. It's perfectly fine.

Comment: $x=\dfrac{\ln(2)+2\ln(3)}{2\ln(3)}$ is probably simpler written as $1+\dfrac{\ln(2)}{2\ln(3)}$ or $1+\ln(2)-\ln(9)$ or many other possibilities.  Your analysis also works with any sensible base to the logarithms and can also for example be written as $1+\log_9(2)$ or $1-\frac{1}{\log_2(9)}$

Comment: Please attach links to these YouTube videos that you search. In this case, the relevant link is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02g-q1v4w0o). Another point : the video proceeds to use decimals before deriving the expression that you obtain (which is correct).

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Good idea, I guess I should probably start trying to get out of the habit of linking the videos in the original equation at the top :\ I have a really weird habit of doing that for some reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly compute

$$
x \ln (9) = \ln(18) $$
$$\Longrightarrow x = \frac{\ln (18)}{\ln (9)}$$

Factoring and using logarithm rules we get

$$x = \frac{\ln (2 \cdot 3^2)}{\ln (3^2)}$$
$$\Longrightarrow x = \frac{\ln (2) + 2\ln(3)}{2\ln (3)}$$

So your result is correct, but with a few extra steps in between.